# autotools is there a short for AC_ARG_ENABLE action-if-given

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I may need to add a lot of `AC_ARG_ENABLE`, currently I'm using the syntax below which is the only I got working, but I wonder if there's already some *m4* macro for a simple *action-if-given* test as I'm using (I did some search but found nothing yet) or a better cleaner syntax.

I've seen some example with it empty `[]` but just can't get it working, do I need to create a new macro?

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([welcome],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-welcome], [Enable welcome route example @<:@default=yes@:>@]),
    [case "${enableval}" in
        yes) enable_welcome=true ;;
        no)  enable_welcome=false ;;
        *) AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-welcome]) ;;
     esac],[enable_welcome=true])
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_WELCOME], [test x$enable_welcome = xtrue])
```

here how I use it on the `Makefile.am`

```
if ENABLE_WELCOME
...
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just separate [`AC_ARG_ENABLE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Package-Options) from handling the option itself, to separate the option handling logic, and keep `configure.ac` easy to read:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([welcome],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-welcome], [... description ... ])],,
  [enable_welcome=yes])

# i.e., omit '[<action-if-given>]', still sets '$enable_welcome'

enable_welcome=`echo $enable_welcome` # strip whitespace trick.
case $enable_welcome in
  yes | no) ;; # only acceptable options.
  *) AC_MSG_ERROR([unknown option '$enable_welcome' for --enable-welcome]) ;;
esac

# ... other options that may affect $enable_welcome value ...

AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_WELCOME], [test x$enable_welcome = xyes])
```

Of course, `autoconf` [promotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Common-Shell-Constructs) the use of portable shell constructs, like `AS_CASE`, `AS_IF`, etc. Probably the "right thing" to do, but I find the syntax annoying. If I get bitten by shell limitations, I guess I'll have to consider them.

If this `yes/no` construct appear frequently, you might define your own function with `AC_DEFUN` requiring a some minimal `m4` concepts. But you should be able to find plenty of examples on how to access function arguments and return values.

Comment: Thanks, I thought, for a simple case where only yes or no are needed there must be already a macro... thought wrong! Or I'm really bad at searching. I think I'll have a lot of those so I better find the minimal/cleanest (maybe I can wrap the case in a loop... will see)

Comment: There's a lot of redundancy on the variable names, prone to errors (IMO)

Comment: @Alex - the learning curve for the autotools is sometimes frustratingly steep. The [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/index.html) is the best *modern* tutorial I know of. Apart from its frustrating site navigation. It even covers some `M4sh` basics if you want to write your own macros.

Answer (score 3):

I took a deeper look to the question and at the moment this below is the syntax most clean, compact and with less redundancy (still too much IMO, I just missed one replace pasting here) I can get working for a simple enable option where I want only `yes` or `no` with a default and an error message:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([form-helper],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-form-helper], [Enable Form helper @<:@default=yes@:>@]),
    [AS_CASE(${enableval}, [yes], [], [no], [],
             [AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-form-helper])])],
    [enable_form_helper=yes])
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_FORM_HELPER], [test x$enable_form_helper = xyes])
```

Comment: Still, this is *much* more readable than the original. And theres' no reason why you can't change `$enable_form_helper` before the `AM_CONDITIONAL` if other options change or override this option.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  Like you, I still find this very annoying!  I've never been an m4 expert, but maybe it's time to dig in.  There has to be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re-invent the wheel here at all. Instead of rolling your own code or clearing the default code via `[]`, just *use* the default code by leaving the action-if-given and action-if-not-given sections unset. The other "trick" here is to use a different test form for options that are enabled by default vs ones that are disabled by default (`!= xno` instead of `= xyes`).

Use this for defaulting to truthy:

```bash
AC_ARG_ENABLE([welcome],
              AS_HELP_STRING([--disable-welcome],
                             [Disable welcome route example]))
AM_CONDITIONAL([WELCOME], [test x"$enable_welcome" != x"no"])
```

Or for if you want the default to be falsey use this arrangement instead:

```bash
AC_ARG_ENABLE([welcome],
              AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-welcome],
                             [Enable welcome route example]))
AM_CONDITIONAL([WELCOME], [test x"$enable_welcome" = x"yes"])
```

Either way you then use in your `Makefile.am` with:

```
if WELCOME
...
endif
```

Comment: Thanks, if it works it's very neat, I haven't worked on an autoconf project in a long time, but if I get the chance I'll try it